# git does not merge all files after resolving conflict

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

So I'm not sure if this is a known issue, but lets go through what happened:

1. I create a feature branch off master, and start working on my feature
2. Master is being updated with other features which I don't have in my own feature branch yet.
3. I am done with my feature branch, and I merge in master into my feature branch so that I solve problems before creating a pull-request to master.  Also, I checkout master and make sure to git pull from origin to get the latest copy of master.
4. I run `git merge master` in my feature branch and get merge conflicts.
   I resolve those conflicts and add everything (conflict files and new/modified files) and then commit.
5. I run `git merge master` again in my feature branch and get `Already up-to-date.`

Now my problem is that some files are not merged from master.  Master clearly has files that have been changed but did not get picked up in my merge.  So now when I make my pull-request it is saying I modified certain files that I never touched and attempting to undo changes in master.

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong and how I can fix this issue?

Comment: So on step 4, are you sure you didn't see any changes that were not yours that you unstaged?

Comment: Yea, I double checked all contents.  Its like literally git decided to stop doing the merge after it reached a certain amount of conflicts.  After I fix the conflicts and commited/pushed back up my feature branch, I then merged the feature branch into our staging branch.  This broke our staging environment and after some research we realized that we were missing code from Master that should have been merged in when I merged master into my feature branch.  And we're talking about code that was merged to master weeks ago, so it SHOULD have gotten merged to my feature branch.

Comment: Somemore context, I just ran in my feature branch:  git diff --name-status master..<Feature Branch> and I get a list of over 30 files that are different between master and my branch.  Obviously I want to get all those files into my feature branch so that I can merge it into our staging branch but git merge says i'm already up to date.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue.  Did you ever happen to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
git merge master
```

---

#### What is the problem and how to fix it?

You are merging your local branch which is not up to date with your remote.

---

#### ***How to fix it?***

Use `git pull origin master` instead of just `git merge master`

---

#### ***What does the previous command does?***

When you pull from origin master it "grab" the code from the remote repository rather then from your local master branch.

Another solution can be like this:

```bash
# Work on your current branch and commit

# Checkout master branch locally
git checkout master

# now update the local copy with the remote code
git pull origin master

# now switch back to your previous branch
git checkout <branch name>

# merge the updated master to your current branch
git merge master
```

As you can see the first solution is much more simple and nicer.

Comment: My master is up to date with origin before making my merge.  I apologize if this was not clear in my original post.